# Inf2Cat Operating Systems Parameter Invalid

Tags: windows, command-prompt, file-generation

I'm trying to generate a .cat file using Inf2Cat.exe. The problem is that I got an error saying: Operating Systems Parameter Invalid. I have followed instructions in [Microsoft Inf2Cat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/inf2cat) and I obtained operating system version identifier from there. What is causing the problem and how to solve it?
[image]

I've tried changing operating system parameter to any of the listed version identifier from Microsoft official documentations (The mentioned link) with no successfulness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command prompt does not treat spaces in file names as a part of the file name itself and cause the problem. So, the solution is to add the driver directory between a double quotation mark. Like this:[image]